# Adjusting the scrollview at the bottom of the page

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have lots of contents on one page so i am using scrollview. I have one scan button at the bottom of the page, which i need to click many times to scan lots of barcodes. when i click on scan button, i am opening "BarcodeScanner" application that will sacn the barcode and returns the result to  my application. so when i come back to my application, again i need to scroll the entire page to click the scan button which is at the bottom side. So is there any way to initialize the scroll at the bottom of the page? Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you putting the Scan Button into the ScrollView...post your xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    s.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
             s.scrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
             // or this
             //s.fullScroll(s.FOCUS_DOWN);
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you think that you can initialise the scroll view.!! If you have lots of contents in a page you have to use scroll view for seeing all the contents. ! Try this, put your scroll view  xml code in to botom of the xml code. and check.!!

Answer (score 0):

Say your ScrollView id is scrollId, the code will lokk like this

```
scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById (R.id.scrollId);
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {            
@Override
public void run() {
       scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
}
```

});

Comment: There is a lag, when it scrolls to bottom and when the content initially shows up on screen